# Getting error while installing angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

i am getting following Warning messages when I tried to install the angular material.

[error messages in command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw8Sj.png)

But in the node|_modules/@angular i have seen the files installed like cdk,material,animations. So how can i overcome the error.

Comment: No git binary found. Failed using git. Please check if you have installed git and in your path?

Comment: you probably need to install git to install angular-material

Comment: and you should probably first `npm init` the directory where you want to install the packages as it has no package.json file for now.

Comment: Is `prave` the root of your project? There's no `package.json` at the location where you are running the command. Also, any reason why you are trying to install `material2-builds` instead of just `material2`?